# Is it possible that Gravity is a Repulsion phenomenon instead of an attractive "force"?

Tags: general-relativity

The classical saying is to say that gravity is an "Attractive" force
meaning that massive objects like a planet will attract other massive objects like an apple. But is it not actually the empty space that repels massive matter away from it forcing it to go towards the nearest massive object because space-time around it is less repulsive?  We do know that a massive object. "Bends" Space time around it. The apple will follow the curve of space time from the less stretched, less repulsive, point of departure to its arrival, in contact with the planet where the space time is stretched the most and least repulsive. The planet warps Space time, But it is the shape of space time that "pushes" the apple to the planet. The apple is in contact with space time at all times while it travels to its destination.

Comment: This isn't a perfect duplicate. There is a difference between gravity as a repulsive force between masses, and gravity as a repulsive force between mass and space. Here is a nice practical demonstration how a space distorsion creates the illusion of an attractive force https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MTY1Kje0yLg .

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the model that I had in mind...

Comment: I suggest you to improve your question along this path: since the space-time distorsion created by any mass is enough to explain the acceleration of any neighbouring mass, couldn't we consider gravity force as an illusion in the same way as centrifugal force is an illusion?